# Hide Workflow from SiteAdmin

Tags: aem, osgi-bundle, sling

We have a requirement in our project like we want to hide some workflows in siteadmin. We are using AEM 6.1. Please let us know if anybody has any solution. any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tushar

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

**Using User Permissions**

This can be controlled by user permissions. The permissions can be updated in useradmin console to remove read permission from the workflow models you want not be shown to user. Permissions can be [managed via groups](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/security/security.html)

Please note that there are 2 workflow models for Schedule Activation/Deactivation, the read access is required for these in case you want user to be able to use "Activate/Deactivate Later" OOTB functionality in siteadmin/damadmin console. These 2 are anyways not shown in workflow list while initiating workflow from siteadmin/damadmin console, but we should take care while removing read permissions.

This solution is verified.

**Using Model changes**

Model can updated to make it as system workflow refer [Adobe Forum Link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1032769?tstart=0). Verify this one with Day Care to see if there is a side effect.